# Class does not have a table or tablename specified and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I tried to add a new table to python/flask -

```
class UserRemap(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255))
    password = db.Column(db.String(64))
    flag = db.Column(db.String(1))

    def __init__(self, name, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.flag='N'
```

Here is table schema -

```
mysql> desc UserRemap;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name     | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| password | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| flag     | char(1)      | NO   |     | N       |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

when i go to interactive python shell and did `from  myapp import db ;` I get this error message,

```
from server import db; Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "server.py", line 74, in
<module>
        class UserRemap(db.Model): 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask_SQLAlchemy-0.15-py2.7.egg/flaskext/sqlalchemy.py",
 line 467, in __init__
     DeclarativeMeta.__init__(self, name, bases, d)  
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative.py",
 line 1336, in __init__
     _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative.py",
 line 1261, in _as_declarative
     "table-mapped class." % cls sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Class <class 'server.UserRemap'> does not have a __table__ or
 __tablename__ specified and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class.
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to mention `__tablename__` or `__table__` to notify sqlalchemy for table in database.

```
class UserRemap(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'UserRemap'
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255))
    password = db.Column(db.String(64))
    flag = db.Column(db.String(1))

    def __init__(self, name, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.flag='N'
```

Comment: Adding `__tablename__` is not necessary if your class has the same name as the table. @lakshmipathi is having this specific issue because he is missing a primary key for the table.

Comment: @volker238, I saw your answer below.

Answer (score 97):

Per the [Flask-SQLAlchemy docs](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/latest/models/) inheriting from `db.Model` will automatically setup the table name for you.

You are seeing this message because you don't have a primary key defined for that table. The error message is unhelpful, but adding a primary key will fix this problem.

Comment: What if I have an abstracted class that has a couple of functions and attributes I want my other classes to inherit from? How shall I handle this inheritance properly?

Comment: Will keep this in mind while creating new tables hereafter. thanks for the details.

Answer (score 4):

Specify `__tablename__` in your class definition.

```
class UserRemap(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'UserRemap'
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255))
```